# Component inside Component - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a hard time to understand this, so I have a component which is already complied which is a `grid`, now when I click on a button a modal pops-up and display another grid inside the modal at this point my code looks like this for the modal pop-up

```
<template>

    <transition v-if="this.modalVisible" v-bind:title.sync="this.modalVisible" name="modal">
        <div class="modal-mask">
            <div class="modal-wrapper">
                <div class="modal-container">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        {{ modalHeaderName }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                     //this is another component
                    <grid-data :grid-values="dummy" :tool-bar="false"></grid-data> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>

</template>

<script>
    import DataTable from './core/gridTable.vue';


    export default {
        components:{
            JqxButton,
            'grid-data' : DataTable,
        },
        props : {
            modalHeaderName : String,
            modalVisible : Boolean
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                buttonWidth: 120,
                buttonHeight: '100%',
                value: this.buttonName,
                dummy : [
                    { name: 'ProductName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'QuantityPerUnit', type: 'int' },
                    { name: 'UnitPrice', type: 'float' },
                    { name: 'UnitsInStock', type: 'float' },
                    { name: 'Discontinued', type: 'bool' }
                ],
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now, the `grid` is a vue component which was already complied and rendered, now will I import it again it says

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- sync here is, getting the value from the updated modal-->
        <custom-modal :modal-visible="this.showModal"  v-bind:showModal.sync="showModal" :modal-header-name="this.modalHeaderName"></custom-modal>
        <JqxGrid :width="width" :source="dataAdapter" :columns="gridValues"
                 :pageable="true" :autoheight="true" :sortable="true"
                 :altrows="true" :enabletooltip="true" :editable="true"
                 :selectionmode="'multiplecellsadvanced'"  :showtoolbar="this.toolBar" :rendertoolbar="rendertoolbar">
        </JqxGrid>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
    import JqxGrid from "../jqx-vue/vue_jqxgrid.vue";
    import CustomModal from "../customModal";
    export default {
        components: {
            JqxGrid,
            'custom-modal' : CustomModal
        },
        // added the name here
        name: 'jqx-grid',
        props : {
            gridValues : Array,
            toolBar : Boolean
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                showModal : false,
                modalHeaderName : '',
                width: '100%',
                dataAdapter: new jqx.dataAdapter({
                     datatype: 'xml',
                     datafields : this.gridValues,
                     url: ''
                }),
                columns: []
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.createButtons();
        },
        methods: {
            rendertoolbar: function (toolbar) {
                let buttonsContainer = document.createElement('div');
                buttonsContainer.style.cssText = 'overflow: hidden; position: relative; margin: 5px;';

                let addButtonContainer = document.createElement('div');
                let deleteButtonContainer = document.createElement('div');

                addButtonContainer.id = 'addButton';
                deleteButtonContainer.id = 'deleteButton';

                addButtonContainer.style.cssText = 'float: left; margin-left: 5px;padding-bottom:25px;';
                deleteButtonContainer.style.cssText = 'float: left; margin-left: 5px;padding-bottom:25px;';

                buttonsContainer.appendChild(addButtonContainer);
                buttonsContainer.appendChild(deleteButtonContainer);
                toolbar[0].appendChild(buttonsContainer);
            },
            createButtons: function () {

                let addButtonOptions = {
                    height: 25, value: '&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-plus" style="padding-top:3px"></i> &nbsp;Add Items &nbsp;',
                };
                let addButton = jqwidgets.createInstance('#addButton', 'jqxButton', addButtonOptions);
                let deleteButtonOptions = {
                    height: 25, value: '&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-ban" style="padding-top:3px"></i> &nbsp;Remove All &nbsp;',
                };
                let deleteButton = jqwidgets.createInstance('#deleteButton', 'jqxButton', deleteButtonOptions);

                // add new row.
                addButton.addEventHandler('click', (event) => {
                    this.showModal = true;
                    this.modalHeaderName = 'Bulk Add Items';
                });
                // delete selected row.
                deleteButton.addEventHandler('click', (event) => {
                   // alert('delete')
                });

            },
            cellsrenderer: function (row, columnsfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties, rowdata) {
                if (value < 20) {
                    return '<span style="margin: 4px; float: ' + columnproperties.cellsalign + '; color: #ff0000;">' + value + '</span>';
                }
                else {
                    return '<span style="margin: 4px; float: ' + columnproperties.cellsalign + '; color: #008000;">' + value + '</span>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I overcome this issue?

I have seen question like this which says the component grid is trying to compile again and hence the error but I am not sure of that, so we should be using the complied version of the grid component.

NOTE: Using Vue with Laravel 5.4

Error Image [image]

Comment: Did you try that code without having the `JqxButton` component? You do not seem to use it in your component. If that isn't the problem, what does `gridTable.vue` contain?

Comment: I have removed the JqxButton usage to reduce the code, I don't think that is an issue. Anyway, I have removed that import now.

Comment: Can you post the content of gridTable.vue. is the HTML wrapped in <template>....</template>? And in the script tag of are you wrapping it in export default { ... }

Comment: Have added the content of the gridTable content, please check @TimWickstrom.com

Comment: Recursive components need a name, otherwise Vue cannot find them, just add `name: 'jqx-grid'` and it should work as expected

Comment: Where should we add the name for the component? @LarsBeck

Comment: @Rehan It goes into the component definition of `JqxGrid`

Comment: After adding the name also, the error is still throwing. @LarsBeck, updated the code.

Comment: You also don't need the `this` keyword in your templates.  `<transition v-if="modalVisible" v-bind:title.sync="modalVisible" name="modal">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see an obvious error when you first posted the code. Right now I see `JqxButton` inside `components` of the upper code block, which would be undefined. In your code, you always import some components for which we can't see the code.

Generally, when I'm in a situation like this and everything seems to be looking okay, I remove all sub-components and see if the error goes away. Then, I re-add one component after each other until I hit the error again and try to debug it there.

From your description, I suspect you have some kind of cycle in your dependencies and you might find [the documentation about circular references](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components) helpful.

Vue needs a lazy import for circular dependencies:

```
components: {
  "my-circular-dependency": () => import("./my-circular-dependency.vue");
}
```

Comment: I added the component using that way but for some reason it is throwing a error an and not compiling properly. What could be the reason?

Comment: Fixed the issue with the `import` and solved the compilation issue using this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993715/how-to-add-dynamic-async-lazy-components-in-vuejs